# Display a random flashcard out of a MYSQL database using python

Tags: python, html, sql, mysql

I am making a web application using HTML, python and a MYSQL database. I currently have two tables: one that stores users and the other that stores flashcards.

I want to add the feature of 'practising' flashcards by displaying a random flashcard from the database one at a time but am unsure how I could approach this.

[Here is my flashcards table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6nls.png)

At first, I was thinking that I could generate a random number and display the card with the respective flashcard ID, but the 'FlashID' doesn't reset per user.

```
SQLController.execute(f"SELECT count(*) FROM flashcards WHERE UserID = '{UserID}'")  
    MaxQuestionsList=(list(SQLController))
    MaxQuestions = str(MaxQuestionsList[0])
    

    RandCard = randint(1,int(MaxQuestions[1]))

    SQLController.execute(f"SELECT Question, Answer FROM flashcarcs WHERE FlashID = '{RandCard}'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Python, but couldn't you just do a random function on a primary key from your SQL database? Like an id of some sort.

You could do `SELECT * FROM flashcards WHERE UserID= '{UserId]'`

then use the function `randint` based on the ID of the SQL Row.

Answer (score 0):

To implement the feature of practicing flashcards by displaying a random flashcard from the database for a specific user, you can follow these steps:

1. **Get the Total Number of Flashcards for the User:**

   - Execute an SQL query to count the number of flashcards associated with the user. This will give you the total number of flashcards that the user has.

   ```py
   SQLController.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM flashcards WHERE UserID = '{UserID}'")
   MaxQuestionsList = list(SQLController.fetchone())  # Use fetchone() to get the count
   MaxQuestions = MaxQuestionsList[0]  # Access the count from the list
   ```
2. **Generate a Random Flashcard ID:**

   - Generate a random number between 1 and the total number of flashcards for the user. This will serve as the FlashID to select a random flashcard.

   ```py
   RandCard = randint(1, MaxQuestions)
   ```
3. **Retrieve the Random Flashcard:**

   - Use the randomly generated `RandCard` to fetch the corresponding flashcard's question and answer from the database.

   ```py
   SQLController.execute(f"SELECT Question, Answer FROM flashcards WHERE FlashID = {RandCard} AND UserID = '{UserID}'")
   flashcard = SQLController.fetchone()
   if flashcard:
       question, answer = flashcard  # Extract the question and answer from the result
       # Now, you can use 'question' and 'answer' to display the flashcard to the user.
   else:
       # Handle the case when there are no flashcards for the user or the provided RandCard is invalid.
   ```

This approach ensures that you select a random flashcard from those associated with the specific user. If there are no flashcards for the user, you should add error handling to deal with that scenario.

Make sure to replace `'UserID'` with the actual user's identifier when executing SQL queries, and ensure proper error handling throughout your code to handle any potential issues with database queries.